# How can I validate my beginSim() is properly generating my Leaderboard list?

Tags: python, simulation, leaderboard

I am new to Python so apologies if this question is basic. I am attempting to write a simulation of a game leaderboard. I'm using a lot of other simulation examples to try to stitch together something that fits my use case. Currently, I'm trying to confirm that when I start my sim, the code properly generates a relatively random Leaderboard of 100 players, with defined names and a randomized value for "Payout". I'm trying to print the Leaderboard with the expectation of seeing each of my playerList values, plus the randomly generated integer between 0 and 23. However, I just get results in bytes: "<**main**.Player object at 0x000001DCC67F4640>".

```
import random

num_in_chat = 24
num_not_in_chat = 76
num_battles = 1 #testing on 1 before adding more


playerList = []
for i in range(num_in_chat):
    playerList.append("F"+ str(i+1))
for i in range(num_not_in_chat):
    playerList.append("NF"+ str(i+num_in_chat+1))

Leaderboard = []


class Player:
    def __init__(self, payout_hour):
        self.rank = range(1,num_in_chat+num_not_in_chat+1)
        self.payout = payout_hour

def beginSim():
    for i in playerList:
        Leaderboard.append(Player(random.randint(0,24))) #I believe this line should randomly generate a payout hour between 0 and 23 for every player 

beginSim()  

print(Leaderboard)
```

The point here is eventually I will want to write rules that simulate how each player will start swapping positions with other players throughout the course of a day (iterating by each minute of the day). If the Leaderboard I start with isn't correct, the rest won't matter.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Please provide the full output of your program

Answer (score 1):

You are printing `Leaderboard` which is list of `Player` type objects.
When you give `print` an object, it tries to convert it into String format.
When you give `print` a list of objects, it will print a list of the string representation of these objects.

A simplification of your issue is that if you have a list like this: `Leaderboard = [Player(1), Player(2)]` python will try to print this: `print([repr(Player(1)), repr(Player(2))])`

Since python doesn't know how to convert `Player` objects into string, it simply prints the object's representation.

You can add an `__str__` method to your `Player` class so that it could be converted to String the way you intend it to, and then also add a `__repr__` method so that it would know how to represent your object in string format.

For example:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, payout_hour):
        self.rank = range(1,num_in_chat+num_not_in_chat+1)
        self.payout = payout_hour

    def __str__(self):
        return "Player({}, {})".format(self.rank, self.payout)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

Comment: You're welcome! If this answered your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)